# Recharts: How to sort order of elements in Tooltip?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recharts

I'm using **Recharts** with **NextJS**. I have a `ComposedChart` of **Line** & **Stacked Bars** like this:

[image: recharts]

The **Stacked Bars** are being rendered from bottom to top, so the **Tooltip**'s order also rendering in ascending order as the chart's state:

[image: recharts]

How can we change the order of the `<Tooltip />` so it will render from the top of the bar to the bottom? (Ex: Yellow -> Gray -> Cyan -> Pastel Cyan)

**Structure of a data object (Each one matches a stacked bar):**

```
[
 {
  aggregated_month: "2021/08"
  deep_sleep_uu: 192 // This one is Gray
  latest_recovery_uu: 159 // Cyan
  recovery_rate: 63.6 // Yellow line
  recovery_uu: 176 // Pastel Cyan
  total_uu: 527 // Number on top
 },
 {
  aggregated_month: "2022/04"
  latest_recovery_uu: 288 // Cyan
  recovery_rate: 76.1 // Yellow
  recovery_uu: 127 // Pastel Cyan
  sleep_uu: 130 // Red bar
  total_uu: 545 // Number on top
 }
]
```

**What I tried:**

1. `<Tooltip itemSorter={() => -1} />` - This is the default
2. `<Tooltip itemSorter={() => 1} />` - This doesn't work either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`itemSorter` has this signature -> `itemSorter?: (item: Payload<TValue, TName>) => number | string` (code [here](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/component/DefaultTooltipContent.tsx#L47)), where `payload` is the following object:

```js
export interface Payload<TValue extends ValueType, TName extends NameType> {
  type?: TooltipType;
  color?: string;
  formatter?: Formatter<TValue, TName>;
  name?: TName;
  value?: TValue;
  unit?: ReactNode;
  dataKey?: string | number;
  payload?: any;
  chartType?: string;
}
```

* You can check the payload object [here](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/component/DefaultTooltipContent.tsx#L24)

This means that you can sort the tooltip by any properties from payload.

Some sort examples:

**SortBy name**

```js
<Tooltip
   itemSorter={(item) => {
      return item.name as string;
   }}
/>
```

**SortBy value (ASC)**

```js
<Tooltip
   itemSorter={(item) => {
      return item.value as number;
   }}
/>
```

**SortBy value (DESC)**

```js
<Tooltip
   itemSorter={(item) => {
      return (item.value as number) * -1;
   }}
/>
```

**Custom sort**

```js
<Tooltip
        itemSorter={(item) => {
          switch (item.dataKey) {
            case "recovery_rate":
              return 0;
            case "deep_sleep_uu":
              return 1;
            case "latest_recovery_uu":
              return 2;
            default:
              return 3;
          }
        }}
      />
```

Said that, as i don´t know your entire code, i believe that what you want can be accomplish sorting by name.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Luis. I tried sorting by `name` but only the Yellow text and the Gray text switch position, it doesn't affect the rest of the Tooltip's content.
Sorting by `value` does affect the whole content but it's not what I'm trying to achieve in this case.

Comment: Did you create an `customtooltip`to show this phrases like 'Number of defected customers'? what is the structure of your data object? I think i can help you -> you want the yellow value always on the top and then Gray -> Cyan -> Pastel Cyan, right?

Comment: The `ComposedChart` receives `data` and there's a default `Tooltip` inside, I'm not using a customtooltip at the moment. I think my current `Tooltip` is displaying the data that matches `dataKey` of the bars. Yes thank you, I want the `Tooltip` to show like what you said.

Comment: I just updated my question with the structure of the data object. Please let me know if it makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Just updated the answer with a custom sort. Check it out! Cheers.